# Donation Alerts

Tags: python

Как работать с DonationAlerts API в Python? Нужно просто получать инфо о донатах (самое начало документации). Я умею работать с библиотекой requests, делал все стандартно, но авторизацию не обнаруживает (хотя она есть). Прошу помочь кодом и объяснениями.

Comment: Покажите сначала ваш код. Как понять не обнаруживает? Заголовок Authorization (или как она там устроена) шлете? Что отвечает?

Comment: ```import requests

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer токен"
}

response = requests.post('https://www.donationalerts.com/api/v1/alerts/donations', headers=headers)
r = response.json()
print(r)```
Все равно пишет, что не авторизовано

Comment: А текст ошибки какой? Все точно по докам? Все scope в наличии https://www.donationalerts.com/apidoc#authorization__scopes? Токен не протух? Может, кто работал именно с этим сервисом, сможет помочь, у меня нет идей... Только эти вопросы

Comment: Вроде все нормально, но я с этим никогда не работал.